# Best practices for consecutive intrusive overlay (Modal)

Tags: usability, guidelines, best-practice, modal, overlay

qq for best practices...

My product has to show the user some regulations about an specific product and ask them to agree with terms (Law terms and regulations), therefore it must be an intrusive overlay, most likely a modal.

Thing is, in some cases the user has to go through the cookie message + regulation message. Once this is an web page, my concern is that with both Interruptions + loading time, this would be a lot of friction before the user even start doing anything.

Is there any know solution? Recos? Guidelines?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches here:

**You don't necessarily have to show everything in a sequence of modals**, you may be able to use a single form for all of them, á la

```
blurb blurb blurb

[ ] I agree to the privacy policy
[ ] I agree to the TOS
[ ] I agree to the other regulations

Select which cookies you want to have: 
[x] Functional [ ] Marketing [ ] Analytics

[ ] Compliance may be enforced by Batman 

[Agree to all] [Save choices] [Reject all]
```

As long as the form doesn't become too crazy with options while still being able to be run through quickly, you may be fine.

**You don't necessarily have to have everything modal.** The cookie notice for example may be non-modal and have you just not set any cookies which require consent until consent is given. Browsers also have the option to broadcast preferences (DNT, Sec-GPC) which you may be able to use to use or not use certain functionality.

**You don't necessarily have to have the user consent to everything**. GDPR has various "legal basis" for data collection, consent is one of them, but contracts and legitimate interest are as well. If you can change the legal basis away from consent, you may be able to avoid excessive user action.

This one is probably the most complex thing to implement, as you need lawyers, designers and all major stakeholders to agree to something. Maybe you can ditch Google Analytics in favor of something that's not cookie based and not as intrusive? Maybe you can have a "by using this site you agree to the TOS"? And, abeit unethical, you maybe can treat regulations as optional and violation payments thereof as the cost of doing business.

Comment: That's a good advice, but I don't believe it works for my case. The "regulations" I was talking about are completely detached from the cookies one, they are related to the product itself (e.g. Alcoholic drinks). So are two different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities I considered was:

1 - Using different components: Modal for the cookies contentment, once this is already built. And instead of using another modal layer, I used a bottom sheet. This way the user at least has some expectation set that would be one more component to interact.

2 - A two step modal. One for each notice.